# lower_bound и iterator

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator> 
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector <int> array;
    int dp=0;
    int n,d;
    vector<int>::const_iterator j;
    cin >> n >> d;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        array.push_back(0);
        cin >> array[i];
    }
    sort(array.begin(),array.begin()+n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i)
    {
        for ( j=lower_bound(array.begin()+i, array.end, array[i]+d); j < n-1; ++j)
        {
            if (*j-1!=0)
            {
                if (array[*j]!=array[*j-1])
            {
                break;
            }
            }
            dp+=1;
        }
    }
    cout << dp;

    return 0;
}
```

не знаю как заставить это работать. перепробовал уже все варианты (auto, iterator, const_iterator). все ломается именно на строке с lower_bound.

no matching function for call to 'lower_bound(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >, , __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >::value_type)'

Comment: Для начала, где скобки после `array.end`?

Comment: Дальше, `j < n-1` сравнивает итератор и индекс. Так нельзя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы поправить ошибки компиляции можно паписать

```
for
(
    j = lower_bound(array.begin() + i, array.end(), array[i] + d);
    j < (array.begin() + n - 1);
    ++j
)
```

еще тут явно нужны проверки на выход за пределы массива при индексировани, например перед `array[*j]`